# Using a background image for one page in rails 4 app?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to give one of my views a background image.  I have found info for rails three on how to do this, but it does not seem to work for me.  Here is the link to the info I used: http://makandracards.com/makandra/2977-declare-different-css-background-images-for-different-locales

Here is my welcome.css.scss:

```
.container {
 background-image: url(images/image.jpg)

  }
```

here is welcome/home.html.erb:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<%= I18n.locale || 'en' %>"     

lang="<%= I18n.locale || 'en'%>">
<body class="container">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that your `images` url works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you won't need to determine a class for the `body` tag - just call `body` in your CSS (and override for the specific page you want the background image on)

Secondly, you need to use [`asset_path` helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_url):

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass
body
  background:
    image: asset-url("image.jpg")
```

This is the "correct" way to call this, as if you use `.erb` or any other other methods with the `asset pipeline`, you run the risk of losing your functionality when you precompile the assets for production

The trick is to use the rails asset [preprocessors](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing) to allow the use of `dynamic` paths for your assets. The paths will be used depending on whether you're using your assets dynamically, or statically ([in production](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production))

Considering you have `image.jpg` in your `/assets/images` folder, the above code should work for you. The SCSS version would be:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
body 
{
  background: {
    image: asset-url("image.jpg");
  }
}
```

--

**Update**

You can call the welcome css like this:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
...
<head>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "welcome" if controller_name == "welcome" %>
</head>
```

Comment: The CSS version rendered an error..said it was expecting a pseudoclass or something after "background".  SCSS version works perfectly though, thanks.

Comment: I just realized this, the background image is still there on my other pages.  I purposely made my welcome controller only have the home page, as that is the only page I want it on.  How do I fix this, I put the SCSS code in welcome.css.scss

Comment: You'll want to only call the `welcome.css.scss` file when you want to have the background as the image. I'll update for you

Comment: So I did this, and then added ' Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( welcome.css ) '  to config/initializers/assets.rb and the background image still appears on every page.  Any ideas?

Comment: This didn't work for me, but the logic makes sense even though the style is being applied to every page. If I have a controller with 2 actions (defs) and one of them being "homepage," how would I modify the last line of code?

Comment: Ok, so I figured out that it's action_name, but it still doesn't work. Style are still being applied to every page.

Comment: Are you sure you have different controllers set up?

Answer (score 0):

CSS File name

welcome.css.scss -> welcome.css.scss.erb

Content

```
background-image: url("<%=image_path('image.jpg')%>");
```

Comment: This isn't recognized as a valid file in Rails. Can you elaborate? I have never heard of adding an erb extension to an scss extension.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was over a year ago, but none of the answers helped me so I figured out something more unorthodox in terms of managing the background image.

```
<% if action_name === "homepage" %>
  <body class="body-change">
<% else %>
  <body>
<% end %>
```

And then in the css.scss you could have something like:

```
.body-change {
    background: red;
}
```

So I'm giving the body a certain class if a condition is met. So if I am on the homepage, the body's class will be something else and then I can add detail to that class in my CSS/SCSS. I hope this helps someone because it worked for me. You can also make the if statement more specific by also specifying a controller_name if you have multiple actions with the same name.

Answer (score -1):

Please update your css file as

```
.container{
    background-image: url("/assets/tooltip.png")
}
```